# ssh authentication nfs

Tags: ssh, nfs, automation

I would like to do ssh from machine "ub0" to another machine "ub1" without using passwords. 
I setup using nfs on "ub0" but still I am asked to insert a password.

Here is my scenario:

- machine ub0 and ub1 have the same user "mpiu", with same pwd, same userid, and same group id
- the 2 servers are sharing a folder that is the HOME directory for "mpiu"
- I did a chmod 700 on the .ssh
- I created a key using ssh-keygene -t dsa
- I did "cat id_dsa.pub >> authorized_keys". On this last file I tried also chmod 600 and chmod 640
- off course I can guarantee that on machine ub1 the user "shared_user" can see the same fodler that wes mounted with no problem.

Below the content of my .ssh folder

```
authorized_keys
id_dsa
id_dsa.pub
known_hosts
```

After all of this calling wathever function "ssh ub1 hostname" I am requested my password.
Do you know what I can try?

I also UNcommented in the ssh_config file for both machines
this line

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
```

I also tried

```
ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/id_dsa mpiu@ub1
```

Below the ssh -vv

```
Code:
OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-3ubuntu1, OpenSSL 0.9.8g 19 Oct 2007
OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-3ubuntu1, OpenSSL 0.9.8g 19 Oct 2007
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ub1 [192.168.2.9] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug1: identity file /mirror/mpiu/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version lshd-2.0.4 lsh - a GNU ssh
debug1: no match: lshd-2.0.4 lsh - a GNU ssh
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-3ubuntu1
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,spki-sign-rsa
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes256-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,arcfour
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes256-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,arcfour
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-md5
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-md5
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client 3des-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server 3des-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 183/384
debug2: bits set: 1028/2048
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Host 'ub1' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /mirror/mpiu/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 1039/2048
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /mirror/mpiu/.ssh/id_dsa (0xb874b098)
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /mirror/mpiu/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
mpiu@ub1's password:
```

I hangs here!

Comment: You say you did `cat id_dsa.pub >> authorized_keys`. Do both the machines have identical SSH keys or did you generate one on each? If they have different keys (which they should!) then you need to take the `id_dsa.pub` from ub0 and put it in `authorized_keys` on ub1 and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Your ssh client is trying password authentication before public key authentication.

Check your `~/.ssh/config` and `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` files for a `PreferredAuthentications` entry.

I see similar behavior if I add the following entry to my `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
PreferredAuthentications password,publickey
```

If you have something like that in either of the aforementioned files, comment it out.